# New Titan X causing infinite login loop on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I got the new Titan X Pascal GPU today installed it, and I am in an infinite login loop. Do I need to install drivers somehow? I have a 4k screen and the resolution it is showing is very low, I think 1024 x 780. Has this happened to anyone else and do you have any ideas?

I also have been trying to install the drivers in Windows, and I have been unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On boot tap shift key a few times just after BIOS screen and the GRUB screen will appear ... pick the one saying Ubuntu extra choices or such (not normal,not restore the 3rd one) ... pick root shell option ... Now we will remove all nvidia drivers to revert temporarily back to nouveau drivers

```
dpkg -l|grep nvidia  # to see what you currently have installed

sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

reboot and it should allow you to login normally however you will be using open source nouveau graphics drivers ... I suggest you now upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 ... then to install latest nvidia drivers

```
System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
```

and pick the one saying  Nvidia version 367.35 which is refreshingly recent and as a bonus will enable you to install the Vulkan SDK

Above UI listing is also available from command line

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

If above does not show recent driver version then checkout [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

tl;dr  identify if your nvidia card has a companion Intel/AMD graphics card which is used normally such that nvidia is auto selected when needed ... although this was more of an issue in prior ubuntu releases

This command will show your graphics card(s)

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

pay particular attention to what is says after

```
Kernel driver in use: xxxxxxx
Kernel driver in use: nvidia   <-- you want this to appear
```

this repo will make visable recent driver releases

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

from above you typically want to install the most recent driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxxxxx   # <-- the latest one
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

Comment: What if nothing shows up for additional drivers?

Comment: initially nothing appears ... after a few seconds it will auto refresh

Comment: Didn't show up so I used sudo apt-get nvidia-current and I am back in am infinite loop